# Posix shared memory cause bus error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, posix, ipc

I used posix shared memory in mips. program complain:

```
i: 516095
i: 516096
Bus error
```

The same program execute in x86 is ok. I want to get kernel max support shared memory size.

```
int ret;
int bufsize = 517120;

shmfd = shm_open(NAME_SHM, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, FILE_OP);
shm_unlink(NAME_SHM);
if(shmfd < 0) {
        sys_err("Create share memory failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
}

ret = ftruncate(shmfd, bufsize);
if(ret < 0) {
        sys_err("Alloc share memory failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
}

char *ptr = mmap(NULL, bufsize,
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
if(ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        sys_err("Mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
}

struct stat buf;
fstat(shmfd, &buf);
printf("size: %d, total: %d\n", buf.st_size, bufsize);

int i;
for(i = 0; i < bufsize; i++) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        ptr[i] = 0;
}
```

I have check ipcs, but man says :

> The  Linux  ipcs utility is not fully compatible to the POSIX ipcs utility.

```
root@AnyWiFi:~# ipcs -lm

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 3
max total shared memory (pages) = 2097152
min seg size (bytes) = 1

root@AnyWiFi:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax 
3740

root@AnyWiFi:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
2097152

root@AnyWiFi:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmni 
4096
```

max seg size is 3k, but my program can use (516096 / 1024 = 504k)?

i am confused by sysv ipc vs posix ipc?

Comment: Why `shm_unlink` is called so early?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shm_unlink() is just called after shm_open() therefore this removes a shared memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object, de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated memory region.  After a successful shm_unlink(), attempts to shm_open() an object with the same name will fail (unless O_CREAT was specified, in which case a new, distinct object is created).

So you are getting a bus error, this a fatal failure in the execution of a machine language instruction resulting from the processor detecting an anomalous condition on its bus. Possibly due to- invalid address alignment (accessing a mullti-byte number at an odd address) or accessing a memory location outside its address space does not exist.

Additionally, you may need to check the resource limits and set the correct limits required by your program (if its smaller), using `sysctl` command

```
$ipcs -l

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 32768
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767

------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 15747
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you might use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) e.g. pseudo-files in `/proc/` (reading them is fast; you need to read them sequentially like pipes and close them quickly).

In particular, you might read `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` & `/proc/sysvipc/shm` etc...

See also [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

You probably should call [shm_unlink(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_unlink.3.html) much later than you do, i.e. after all use of your shared memory.